# How to trigger multiple event on different html element but inside one jQuery function

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I need to trigger 2 events in same one but from different HTML elements. What I mean is that I have search text box and a search button. I need to display search results on `keyup` inside the search text box **OR** when the search button is clicked.

I found this answer on stack overflow but it is meant to be used by just one element and several events:

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event fired
});
```

Is it possible or should I duplicate my script but change the event for each element ?

What I am using is:

```
$('#searchBtn').on('click',function() 
{ 
    surfData(); 
});

$('#searchTxt').on('keypress',function() 
{ 
    surfData(); 
});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: Give me just 10 minutes I am testing something and I will post all the script for you guys

Comment: Just define a new class and assign it to both elements. Use that element for event delegation and you're done.

Comment: @hallleron didn't get what you mean, please look at my current script that I will add in a minutes and if I can use different thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this but it will have the side effect of triggering the callback (and your `surfData` function) when the searchBtn element registers a key press event as well as when the searchTxt element is clicked on (the latter being a very common way a user selects a text box). I believe @hallleron's will have the same problem.

```
$('#searchBtn, #searchTxt').on('click keypress',function() 
{ 
    surfData(); 
});
```

To avoid those side effects you'd need to leave the code you have (which is extremely simplified already; below is the only simplier version I could think of)

```
$('#searchBtn').click(surfData);
$('#searchTxt').keypress(surfData);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I meant with "define a class for them":

```js
$('.search_elem').on('keyup click', function(){
  console.log("Event fired!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="search_elem" type="text" placeholder="search ...">
<button class="search_elem">Start search</button>
```